# How to add angular support in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I tried adding angularJS to Intellij following this [guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-angularjs.html), but the problem is that I am unable to access Java Script option inside Languages and Frameworks, and therefore I cannot change libraries. Any ideas how to make it appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free edition of IntelliJ does not support Javascript.  For that you need to purchase Ultimate.